# Prevent simultaneous execution of stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, locking

I have a stored procedure which insert a record to a table with sequential token number. I have another stored procedures which also will insert record into same table.

I will execute these stored procedures from different users of a web application.

As an example i have a page in my web application named AddUser which can be accessed by OfficerA and OfficerB. Both these officers can simultaneously press the add button which will execute my stored procedure simultaneously. If done so the 2 new users will get same token number which should not happen.

I want to create a locking mechanism when if one officer executes the procedure the other officers execution should WAIT till the first one completes.

I have tried the following. but not sure its enough for the WAIT process

```
create procedure TokenInsertProc(<params here>)
as
begin
DECLARE @returnCode INT

 BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN TRY
      EXEC @returnCode = sp_getapplock
            @Resource = 'TokenInsertProc',
            @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
           @LockOwner = 'Transaction',
           @LockTimeout = 50,
           @DbPrincipal  = 'public'

    IF @returnCode NOT IN (0, 1)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ( 'Unable to acquire exclusive Lock on TokenInsertProc', 16, 1 )       
        RETURN
    END

-- my procedure insert script goes here 

 EXEC @returnCode = sp_releaseapplock
                        @Resource = 'TokenInsertProc',                       
                        @LockOwner = 'Transaction',
                        @DbPrincipal  = 'public'

 COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    IF @returnCode IN (0, 1)
        BEGIN
             EXEC @returnCode = sp_releaseapplock
                     @Resource = 'TokenInsertProc',                       
                        @LockOwner = 'Transaction',
                        @DbPrincipal  = 'public'
        END    

        DECLARE @ErrMsg VARCHAR(4000)
        SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE()       
        RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, 15, 50)   

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH;
end
```

or putting just
`set transaction isolation level serializable`
will help?

```
create procedure TokenInsertProc(<params here>)
as
begin
DECLARE @returnCode INT
 set transaction isolation level serializable
 BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN TRY

-- my procedure insert script goes here 


 COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH;
end
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

**Edit 1**

For more clarification let me post the table structure

```
TQHId         TokenNo   TokenStatus TokenSequence
1               A1      Pending     1
6               A2      Pending     2
7               B1      Pending     1
9               I3      Hold        3
10              I4      Pending     4
```

Here in this table

```
[TQHId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_TokenQHeader] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TokenQHeaderId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

is identity field which doesn't have any relationship with tokenno. i use it as a primary key field.
My Token Numbers are generated using a custom code inside **TokenInsertProc** procedure.

As i mentioned my issue is that this stored procedure may get called by two different web users simultaneously. I want to avoid getting same token num(only when procedure gets executed) to 2 different users.

Comment: It much depends on your proc and table. Provided the proc inserts the row with the table's PK value you generally only need to catch PK exception.

Comment: My Primary key field is a identity field with increment 1

Comment: "If done so the 2 new users will get same token".  Something seems wrong with your setup.  Have you considered using a sequence or `identity` column so this cannot happen?

Comment: You might read about [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). SQL-Server has built-in support for this...

Comment: An identity column can handle concurrent requests. That's one of the reasons it was built for in the first place. No special treatment is required from your end to handle this situation.

Comment: You might also want also want to read [SQL Server’s identity column misconceptions](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/10/06/sql-servers-identity-column-misconceptions/) over on my blog.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have edited my question. Please help

Comment: @ZoharPeled did you got a clarity? Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: @GordonLinoff, still am i wrong somewhere

Comment: If you're using an identity column or a sequence, you wont have problems with concurrent executions.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, so you mean i shouldnt go for locking? but as i mentioned already my token numbers are generated by custom script inside this stored procedure

Comment: I'm saying you shouldn't generate your token using a custom script, when there are working solutions you can get out the the box.

Comment: @ZoharPeled. Thank you for your help. But i must generate  token using custom code because there can be different departments and counters and other conditions based on which tokens are generated